# I am getting: TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include()

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, typeerror, urlconf

My root urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('webarticles.urls')),
]
```

While I have seen this error answered on stackoverflow before, they don't seem to work for me. Specifically there are 2 components of the answers that confuse me:

1. Why url is used instead of path
2. If I am to import webarticles, how to do that given that my project and app are on the same level

Thank you for any help you are able to provide!

Comment: add your `webarticles.urls` module

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your urls.py in webarticles app has the following too:

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Or whatever url list you are using in your app.

Answer (score 0):

======== For Project urls.py ========

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include("webarticles.urls")),

]
```

======== For webarticles (app) urls.py ========

```
from django.urls import path
from webarticles.views import *


urlpatterns = [
    path('',DemoView1,name="demo1"),
    path('demo2/', DemoView2, name="demo2"),
    path('demo3/', DemoView3, name="demo3"),

]
```